# How to get the time in hours between these two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have one table in that they are four columns like

```
startdate varchar(15),
enddate varchar(15),
starttime varchar(15),
endtime varchar(15)
```

Here I need to get the time in hours between these two dates (ex: 6/7/2010,6/12/2010) if I pass these days as inputs.

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: 1) Make those columns use `DATETIME` 
2) Use DATEDIFF on your new DATETIME columns....

Answer (score 2):

It's usually as simple as:

```
select datediff(hour, starttime, endtime)
```

For example:

```
select datediff(hour, '2010-01-01 12:00', '2010-01-02 13:45')
```

Prints:

```
25
```

Comment: I think you have the endtime and starttime parameters the wrong way around! This will return a negative value, which is probably not correct given the way the question is worded.

Comment: thanx barry .but here i am using two dates as inputs parameters  and i need to get time as output

Comment: +1, you could even do this like `select datediff(minute, '2010-01-01 12:00', '2010-01-02 13:45')/60.0` and still get hours, but with more precision: `25.750000`

Answer (score 1):

Use the SQL [DateDiff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258269(SQL.80).aspx) function:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(hh, startdate, enddate)
```